# Mod menu -> Merge - doesn't check for URL on submit click

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

Opening the merge option on the mod menu and clicking the submit button (or did I press enter, I forget now) didn't check to see if I had entered anything into the textbox. Then I got the "oops, something bad happened" screen (where I realized immediately I had ID10Ted the menu option.

EDIT: Since someone is going to say "so?":

Can we add a validation for that? Ya know, so nobody else fatfingers this like I did, generating excess error reports...